# how to use firstOrNew if it is first or new

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want use firstOrNew like something this:

```
table::firstOrNew(['ip'=>'15.25.36.12', 'linke'=>'http://example.com'])
->where('created_at','>=',date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-86400);
```

i used something this :

```
    $data = table::where('ip', '15.25.36.12')->where('link','http://example.com')->
where('created_at','>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-86400));
    if(!$data->exists())
    {
      $data = new table;
      $data->field = 'foo';
      $data->save(); 
    }
```

but it didn't work very well !  Coz it add 2 row same

Comment: Did you try to use `firstOrCreate()` method on `where` builder like this: `data::where()->firstOrNew([])`? I'm just interesting

Comment: Yeah, I don't want use `firstOrCreate()` Coz it isn't my target. I want create new `Row` at data that if it already exists `redirect()` to other page

Comment: method `firstOrNew` does actually the same as you do. Under the hood: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/08095be5f7bc95c2a5126060bc215bcd2a99a39f/Eloquent/Builder.php#L235

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, the **firstOrNew** searches for the record in database with given information. If found then returns the model instance containing the record info else only creates a new Model instance, **it does not save the content** for this you have to manually fire save.

Example

```
// Assuming that this record does not exist in database
$a = Table::firstOrNew([
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age'  => 16
]); 

$a->nickname = "jDoe";
$a->save(); // Save the record to the database using insert
```

This gives you chance to add other relevant information to the object before saving.

In order to create the record at the very instant then use **firstOrCreate** function. It will also return a model instance but would also have created the record at the same time. Now if you do save it will fire a update query.

Example

```
// Assuming that this record does not exist in database
$a = Table::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age'  => 16
]); 

$a->nickname = "jDoe";

// Fires a update query as opposed to insert query in above example
$a->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs:

"The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the given attributes."

"The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it."

So either `save()` your new record, or use `firstOrCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
$data = table::updateOrCreate([
                              'ip'=>'15.25.36.12', 
                              'linke'=>'http://example.com'
                               ],[
                               'field' => 'foo'
                             ])
                    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=',Carbon::now()->subDay());
```

Comment: `updateOrCreate` is for older version of `Laravel`, I use version 5.2